# All icons missing after modifying a custom entity

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm-4

Today I did something I've been meaning to do for a while. I got around to creating some icons for the two custom entities I created a while ago. These custom entities were Account Product and Contact Product. I used a microsoft tool to import and publish the new icons. This seemed to work ok. The problem is now the only icons that show up in the entire CRM are the two new icons. All the rest are just blank with little red dots. This isn't the case on the computer I made the change from. All icons are present there. But from every other computer all icons are missing. I seems to be some sort of permission thing but I'm blowed if I know know what it is.

Please help. Any ideas?

Image available here http://i244.photobucket.com/albums/gg14/chimpsinties/Temp/Clipboard01.jpg

Here is the post I followed with a link to the tool http://mscrmtools.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/updating-custom-entities-icons.html

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that sort of image in Dynamics when you need to publish all the customisations.

Comment: Forgot to publish my customizations after import thanks for the reminder Dean :)